# xcode 4.2 iOS Tableview using storyboard

Tags: ios, tableview, storyboard

I created a iOS tabbed application using xcode 4.2 and storyboard. I added one tableviewcontroller with custom cell on it, when clicking the row, I want to open one tableviewcontroller, i used the following code below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
categoryClass *cc = [datas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

iSubProducts *subProducts = [[iSubProducts alloc] init];
subProducts.title = cc.categoryName;
subProducts.catID = cc.categoryID;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:subProducts animated:YES];
[subProducts release];


}
```

but when I click the row it gives me the following error:

* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

on my iSubProducts tableviewcontroller, i have the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCell2";

iSubProductsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

productSubClass *cc = [datas2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Product Name: %@", cc.productName);
cell.txtProductName.text  = cc.productName;
cell.txtProductDesc.text = cc.productDesc;

return cell;

}
```

I assume this is where the error occurs, the cell is returning a nil value. When I try to attach the iSubProducts tableviewcontroller using or from a button, it all works fine, but if its coming from row clicked, this error shows up.

Im quite new with iOS development, and maybe there is a error opening tableviewcontroller from a tableviewcontroller with a custom cell on it. I've been bangin my head for 2 days now and googled a lot, unfortunately I didn't find any solution. I'm pretty sure there's no error on the iSubProducts tableviewcontroller since its working if i tried pushing it from a button. Please I need advice on this one, Im so stucked right now with this issue. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 6):

note sure how beneficial this is.. but just today I had trouble moving from one tableview to another view after clicking the row..

I stayed completely away from DidSelectRowAtIndexPath.  Instead I used the segue (which was what I was aiming at).

this code snipped is from apple's storyboard example that uses tables.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007416-Classes_RootViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_10

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSelectedPlay"]) {
            NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
            detailViewController.play = [dataController objectInListAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
    }
}
```

This all assumign you start using the segues in the storyboard feature and make sure to use the identifiers for the segues.

Comment: I think this is correct - the problem in the code above is that the new table view controller is being allocated / inited directly and not loaded from the storyboard, which means that the prototype cells are not available. Using segues and configuring the target view controller in prepareForSegue will solve this, alternatively it could be instantiated from the storyboard but that seems unncecessary code.

Comment: wow, this nailed the problem, thanks man! all I can say is oh my god! thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a prototype cell first in the designer so that you can drag out a segue from the cell to the destination view.